# Facing issues in accessing phpmyadmin in vagrant scotch

Tags: vagrant, lamp

I want to access phpmyadmin in vagrant scotch.But i don't know how to access the phpmyadmin.
Example: http://192.168.33.10/ is default addres
is there any specific url like this to access phpmyadmin.
Thanks.

Comment: did you install it ? as far as I know phpmyadmin does not come in scotch box, they recommend using a [desktop client](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/introducing-scotch-box-a-vagrant-lamp-stack-that-just-works#database-access)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install phpmyadmin, since it does not come with scotch by default. Once you have this installed simply go to: http://192.168.33.10/phpmyadmin.

Comment: is it possible to install via terminal ??

Comment: Yes, Access your vagrant ssh environment or Virtualbox, then follow this tutorial. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin